# Usage of nested protocol (member of protocol is also a protocol)

Tags: python-3.x, mypy, python-typing, pyright

Consider a Python protocol attribute which is also annotated with a protocol. I found in that case, both mypy and Pyright report an error even when my custom datatype follows the nested protocol. For example in the code below `Outer` follows the `HasHasA` protocol in that it has `hasa: HasA` because `Inner` follows `HasA` protocol.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Protocol

class HasA(Protocol):
    a: int

class HasHasA(Protocol):
    hasa: HasA

@dataclass
class Inner:
    a: int

@dataclass
class Outer:
    hasa: Inner

def func(b: HasHasA): ...

o = Outer(Inner(0))
func(o)
```

However, mypy shows the following error.

```
nested_protocol.py:22: error: Argument 1 to "func" has incompatible type "Outer"; expected "HasHasA"  [arg-type]
nested_protocol.py:22: note: Following member(s) of "Outer" have conflicts:
nested_protocol.py:22: note:     hasa: expected "HasA", got "Inner"
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/7041) which is almost exactly the same as your example. I think the [motivating case on the `mypy` docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html#covariant-subtyping-of-mutable-protocol-members-is-rejected) explains quite well why this is illegal. Bringing a structural analogy to your example, let's fill in an implementation for `func` and tweak `Inner` slightly:

```py
def func(b: HasHasA) -> None:
    b.hasa.a += 100 - 100

@dataclass
class Inner:
    a: bool

o = Outer(Inner(bool(0)))
func(o)
if o.hasa.a is False:
    print("Oh no! This is still False!")
else:
    print("This is true now!")
```

This is of course a contrived example, but it shows that if the type-checker didn't warn you against this, the inner protocol can type-widen the inner type and perform value mutation, and you may silently perform type-unsafe operations.

As suggested by the `mypy` documentation, the solution is to make the outer protocol's variable read-only:

```py
class HasHasA(Protocol):
    @property
    def hasa(self) -> HasA:
        ...
```